# How do I grab meta data from other websites and display on mine in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When using FB or Google + I can paste a link of any website into the status update box and it will instant load information about that website with the option of flicking through thumbnail images.

How can I go about achieving this in ruby on rails? All my searches seem to bring up php methods on how to do this.

For grabbing video data  info I use the Ruby Open Graph Protocol gem. Is there any thing for grabbing data the way FB and G+ do? If not is there a standard way this is done in rails/ruby, if so.. how is this done?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like oembed. I've found a gems for that, so I propose you to take look at it: https://github.com/judofyr/ruby-oembed or https://github.com/embedly/embedly-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You should likely use a gem like http://nokogiri.org/

It allows you to work with a html page just as you would do with jQuery. Very handy.